# Add mathematical notation (dot above letter) to flextable

Tags: r, flextable

I would like to add mathematical notation: [image: V ̇ O2peak] to my flextable.

This is my mwe and attempt:

```
df = data.frame(item = c("vo2", "age"),
                mean = c(30,40))
df

flextable(df)%>%
  mk_par(i=1, j=1, as_paragraph(" $\dot{V}$O", as_sub(2peak) ))
# also attempted

flextable(df)%>%
  mk_par(i=1, j=1, as_paragraph(as_equation($\dot{V}$O), as_sub(2peak) ))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `as_equation()` that expects MathJax syntax:

```
library(flextable)
df <- data.frame(
  item = c("vo2", "age"),
  mean = c(30, 40)
)

flextable(df) |>
  mk_par(i = 1, j = 1, as_paragraph(
    as_equation("\\dot{V}0_{2peak}")
  ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why it is aligning right in the cell in real data?

Comment: as you can see in my example, it's not right align. If you get right align cell, maybe you used a theme that do so, usually flextable align number on the right. If you want to change alignment, use function `align()`

Comment: Actually I think it is right align, but you can't tell as cell is small. I've asked a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77612377/flextable-equation-aligning-right-in-cell

Comment: there is a width associated with the formula, I guess this is what is bothering you then (see argument width of as_equation in the documentation). We can't know how large it will be so you could set it roughly manually and you should get what you want