# Flextable equation aligning right in cell

Tags: r, flextable

I am creating a `flextable` with mathematical notation in one cell. @David Gohel has assisted me with this:

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  item = c("vo2", "age"),
  mean = c(30, 40)
)

flextable(df) %>%
  mk_par(i = 1, j = 1, as_paragraph(
    as_equation("\\dot{V}0_{2peak}")
  ))
```

However, the maths notation is right aligning (not apparent above as cell is small). Here are examples demonstrating:

```
flextable(df) %>%
  mk_par(i = 1, j = 1, as_paragraph(
    as_equation("\\dot{V}0_{2peak}")
  ))%>%autofit()
```

[image]

```
flextable(df) %>%
  mk_par(i = 1, j = 1, as_paragraph(
    as_equation("\\dot{V}0_{2peak}")
  ))%>%width(j=1, 2)
```

[image]

```
flextable(df) %>%
  mk_par(i = 1, j = 1, as_paragraph(
    as_equation("\\dot{V}0_{2peak}"), "some text"
  ))%>%autofit()
```

[image]

With the annotation I would like to use (I'd like the dagger symbol to be next to VO2peak, on same line, left aligned):

```
flextable(df) %>%
  mk_par(i = 1, j = 1, as_paragraph(
    as_equation("\\dot{V}0_{2peak}"), "†"
  ))%>%autofit()%>%align(j=1, align = "left")

flextable(df) %>%
  mk_par(i = 1, j = 1, as_paragraph(
    as_equation("\\dot{V}0_{2peak}†")
  ))%>%autofit()%>%align(j=1, align = "left")
```

[image]
[image]

Why is the equation cell right aligning, and can I add  text after it but keep it on the same line?